# mysqldump and restore with special characters. øæåØÆÅ

Tags: mysql, silverstripe

Locally I do this to dump and move a database, upgrading  silverstripe 2.3 to 2.4:

```
mysqldump --opt  --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset --user=$root -p$password $oldDatabase -r db.sql  

iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF8 db.sql > db_utf.sql 


CREATE DATABASE $newDatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $newDatabase . * TO '$newUser'@'localhost';  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET NAMES utf8; SOURCE db_utf.sql;
```

And it works, but on the server Ubuntu 8.04, with mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a.
I get crazy `√∏` characters instead of `øæåØÆå`.

Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I tried the different solutions here without luck. Then I tried alternative 2 in this blog: [http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/05/mysql-database-migration-and-special-characters/](http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/05/mysql-database-migration-and-special-characters/), and it solved the problem. Appearently a bug in mysqldump is the cause of the problem.

Comment: SOLUTION can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152288/loading-utf-8-encoded-dump-into-mysql/ As many of us, use **.php** commands to do a backup,
you may be unable to correctly export the database with UTF8 data. so, the problem is, that you need to use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` after mysql_connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. ssh the server and connect.
2. create db dump running

`mysqldump -h my_guid.cloud.database.com -u my_user -p my_database_name -r ~/my_db_backup.sql`

The console will prompt and ask for the password and there you can type it, my pwd had special characters so i was able to run this command with ease

Answer (score 30):

Try to run with the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database -r output.sql
```

instead of redirecting the output with arrow '>'

Comment: But why does this fix it?

Comment: @Brian, maybe because when we use '>' to write in any file it uses default encoding from our OS. In my case, CentOS.  But when we use -r flag we let mysqldump handle file write, and thus don't have encoding problems. If you try any command followed by '>' to write a file it will work because the OS just write what would be printed in the bash cli.

Comment: I hope someone will explain what is the difference between > and -r option.

Answer (score 19):

It took me Two days to find out
I had the same problem and solved it when trying  to export a database in arabic using mysqldump 
and each time you open the outputfile in notepad++ its encoding is in ansi and you need it to be utf-8  my code for export and import was as follows it turns out i was right but i was checking the database on the terminal but the terminal doesn't support encoding and i just tried checking it with phpmyadmin and its good don't try to open the file in notepad++
or just try your application directly it will work.

export command

`mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 dbname > outputfile  //or even if you use -r instead of > no difference`

import command 

`mysql -uuser -ppassword --default-character-set=utf8 dbname < outputfille // please take in mind this does override existing database`

Comment: Try it, i did have the same problem, if doesn't work let me now,when it does please check this as correct answer

Comment: `--default-character-set=utf-8` should be `--default-character-set utf8` and `--default=character-set=utf-8` should be `--default-character-set utf8`

Comment: I just spend hours testing a dump / restore cycle and it is worth noting that `utf8` in mysql is not exactly `utf8`. What is more likely needed is actually `--default-character-set=utf8mb4`. I suggest that in order to (more) fully verify your restore ability and see this for yourself then store a page full of emojis in the database and try a backup/restore. I have confirmed this works on local dump to local restore and AWS Aurora RDB dump to local restore. 

Answer (score 6):

This fixed the issue for me.

1. Import the double encoded input.sql
2. Export it again `mysqldump -h "$DB_HOST -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" --opt --quote-names --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 "$DB_NAME" > output.sql`
3. Import clean output.sql

[How to restore the database double encoded by mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626218/how-to-restore-the-database-double-encoded-by-mysqldump)

Answer (score 5):

It's very important to make sure the client is set to UTF8. Confusingly, it's not the same as setting your database to UTF8.  Open /etc/my.cnf and make sure you have default-character-set = utf8 under [mysql] not just under [mysqld]

Now you should be able to pipe UTF8 dumps directly into the mysql client.  I also recommend using the option --hex-blob on the mysqldump command as mysqldump is not perfect.

Comment: ** If you disagree with this - please comment

Answer (score 5):

**I succeed as follows**:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u ..
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it without the `iconv` step?

Here's what I use when dumping UTF-8 databases:

```
mysqldump \
    -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" \
    --default-character-set=Latin1 \
    --result-file=$DATAFILE
```

And to restore:

```
mysql -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" \
    --default-character-set=latin1 < $DATAFILE
```

Comment: Still skewed up characters are in the db.sql file! Ã where å should be.

Comment: How are you checking the output file? Not all text editors are UTF-8 compatible, so may display a correct file incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just copy the tables to $newDatabase as latin1.
Then, for each table, execute:

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci
```

Comment: I've been looking at the mysqldump and no matter what default-character-set I use I get encoded letters:Ã. But if I look at the same data in mysql the letters are fine ø; So the problem is getting the data out not putting it in.

Comment: Can you stop mysql temporarily with `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql stop` ? Or are you on some production server which must not stop? If you can stop mysql, you can directly copy the database in /var/lib/mysql. Once you've backed that up, restart mysql with `sudo invoke-rc.d mysql start` and then perhaps you can try the `ALTER TABLE` command above directly on the current database tables. It should convert you to utf8 without using `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 1):

Only way that worked for me was to export the utf-8 tables as latin-1 (character set of file: iso-8859-1) in phpmyadmin.

Open the exported file in notepad++
convert to UTF8 (with BOM)

Then upload file and import with SOURCE dump.sql.